# Node.JS with RedisStore session timeout

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

i'm using Redis to store sessions in my node.js app, hosted on heroku, but redis is keeping the session stored, how can i make them expire automatically?

My express app is configured this way:

```
var app = express.createServer(
  express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: 31557600000 }),
  express.cookieParser(),

    express.session({ secret: 'secret', store: new RedisStore({
          host: 'myredishost',
          port: 'port',
          pass: 'myredispass',
          db: 'dbname'
      })})
);
```

Answer (score 5):

As the Connect session middleware docs state, you need to set the maxAge property on the cookie object:

```
express.session({ secret: 'secret', store: ..., cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }});
```

Read more about that here: http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-session.html

Comment: but it deletes the session stored on redis too? or just the user cookie? it would be nice if i could set the keys expire time, like this: http://redis.io/commands/expire

Comment: It deletes the session, and probably the cookie also I'm not sure. Anyway set the max age and the session will expire by itself.

Comment: MaxAge sets expire time for redis key, so key will remove from db after expire time

Answer (score 1):

They will expire based on the cookie if you're using req.session.cookie.maxAge.