# What should I do to store data to session with connect-redis

Tags: javascript, session, node.js, express

I want to store `username` of an account to session. I working with node.js by expressjs framework and I tried to use `connect-redis` to store session like tutorial of [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/guide.html). 
 Pls show me how to store and get data of variable

Comment: So what's the problem actually?

Comment: I don't know to save and get data of a session with `connect-redis`

Comment: `req.session.my_var = 1` to set a var, `req.session` to access the session variables.

Comment: when i use **`User.authenticate(req.body.login, req.body.password,function(err, docs){
  if(docs.length == 0) {
   res.redirect('back');
  } else {
   if(docs[0].role == 'admin'){
    res.redirect('/admin');
   } else {
    res.redirect('/');
   }
   req.sessions.user = docs[0];
  }
 });`**
 then recive this error **`Cannot set property 'user' of undefined`**

Comment: It's `req.session` not req.sessions (delete the last s).

Comment: it still having error like that.. `Cannot set property 'user' of undefined`

Comment: can you create a snippet at jsfiddle.net and post the link.

Comment: here is [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/enZo/F2WQQ/)

Answer (score 0):

Yours looks mostly right, just incomplete. I assume you also have redis running and have included connect higher up. Here's a slightly more complete version: http://jsfiddle.net/F2WQQ/1/

Comment: Hi, Jed. My redis-server run,  but It still error like that. :(

Comment: Have you tried configuring your RedisStore as here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674138/node-js-with-redisstore-session-timeout

Answer (score 0):

Once you configure your expressSession with redis-connect, immediately add the following function:

```
expressApp.use(function(req, res, next) {

    if(req.session.user){
        console.log("Session variable already set: " + req.session.user);            
    }
    else{
        req.session.user = 'username';
        console.log("Session variable not set");
        console.log("Setting Session variable now: " + req.session.user);
    }
})
```

Now you can use this session variable anywhere in your nodejs app.